# Cross-origin error on trying to render a component after data fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Here is my Search component.

```
class Search extends Component {
state = {
    hcpName: [],
    hcps: [],
    showTab: false,
    searchName: '',
    isLoading: false,
    page_id: 2,
    page_id_name: 1,
    hcp_id: 101,
    receivedData: [],
    nameData: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchingData();
}


hcpNamesFetch = () => {
    return axios.get('/get-hcp-data')
        .then((res) => {
            const hcps = res.data;
            console.log('MD list data: ', res.data)
            this.setState({ ...this.state, hcps: hcps, hcpName: Object.values(hcps.hcp_details_concat) })
            // console.log('MD name in : ', this.state.hcps.hcp_overview.name)
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(`Error: $(error)`));
}

dataFetch = () => {
    let page_id = this.state.page_id;
    let hcp_id = this.state.hcp_id;
    console.log('state: ', this.state);
    axios.post('/test-json', {
        page_id: page_id,
        hcp_id: hcp_id
    })
        .then((res) => {
            const dataRequest = res.data;
            console.log('State before loading data: ', this.state);
            console.log('received data', res.data);
            this.setState({ ...this.state, receivedData: res.data });
            console.log('State after loading data: ', this.state);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

nameFetch = () => {
    let page_id_name = this.state.page_id_name;
    let hcp_id = this.state.hcp_id;
    console.log('state: ', this.state);
    axios.post('/test-json', {
        page_id: page_id_name,
        hcp_id: hcp_id
    })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('Name received data', res.data);
            this.setState({ ...this.state, nameData: res.data });
            console.log('State after loading data from name: ', this.state);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

fetchingData = () => {
    axios.all([this.hcpNamesFetch(), this.dataFetch(), this.nameFetch()])
        .then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
            const responseOne = responses[0];
            const responseTwo = responses[1];
            const responseThree = responses[2];
            console.log(responseOne, responseTwo, responseThree)
        }))
        .catch(error => console.error(`Error: $(error)`));

    
}

render() {
   return (
   <div>
       {this.state.receivedData.length !== 0 && <Name data={this.state.receivedData} />}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12" style={{ padding: 0 }}>
                    <div class="tabs-container-fluid">
                        <MidTabs />
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            {this.state.receivedData.length !== 0 && <Dashboard data= 
                                        {this.state.receivedData} />}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
   </div>
```

As you can see in the code, I'm making a few axios requests. The problem that I'm having currently is that I want to display both the Name and Dashboard component after I get data in the receivedData state. When I comment out the line where I conditionally render Name, it works fine and I can see the Dashboard component after I get data from axios. But when I add the Name component line, I get a cross-origin error  like this: "Unhandled Rejection (Error): A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information."

Why am I getting that error only for the name component and not for the Dashboard component. Because when I use the Dashboard component individually by cutting out the line of Name component, the application works fine. I want to resolve that erro.

Comment: What is your question? Do  you send a cross-origin request or do you use a cross-origin CDN?

Comment: No I'm getting an error when I try to render the components after I receive the data in the state. The name of the error is cross-orgin error. Also, am I using the correct approach to conditionally render these components?

Comment: You get a cross-origin error without cross-origin request? Do you use a CDN for  React?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. How can I check whether I use a CDN?

Comment: How do you import React into your project? It's described in the link you posted in your question.

Comment: I did npm install and then this line: import React, { Component } from 'react';

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], e.g. with Stackblitz.com